# How to properly open a file in python and have the text contents printed out

Tags: python, file

I am trying to open an existing file called sun_og.text.
Below is my code. I want what is written in the file to print out in my terminal.

```
f = open("sun_og.txt", "r")
file_contents = f.read()
print (file_contents)
file.close()
```

But I keep getting this error message

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sun_og.txt'
```

Comment: The error looks quite clear, try providing the full path

Comment: I am very new to coding, can you explain what you mean @gogaz ?

Comment: Just get the path of the file (it'll look like "C://Windows/User/Me/Documents/..." for example on my computer (as I have a Windows laptop))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that your script isn't located in the same directory as the text file, which is why this error is being raised.

To fix this, **try providing an absolute/relative filepath.**

Also, **when handling files, it's better to use `with`** as it automatically closes the file for you.

So try this:

```
with open("your_path/sun_og.txt", "r") as f:
    file_contents = f.read() ## You only need this line if you're going to use the file contents elsewhere in the code
    print(file_contents) ## Otherwise, you could remove the line above and replace this line with print(f.read())
```

Alternatively, you could **use the `os` module as you can use its `chdir` function to relocate to another directory** (in this case, the directory of your text file). See @Jones1200's answer for more information.

Comment: @V.Sel No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `os` module to go to the directory, where your text-file is.

```
import os

directory_of_text = r'Your/Directory/with/text_file'
os.chdir(directory_of_text)
```

use your code after that and it should work.